Taurus. How to use Scenario-Level properties in include-scenario block
I have 10 features to test. For that I wrote 10 test scripts.
Each test script use different username/password to login to website.
I would like to use same login code with each test script but everytime it should use Username/password specific to that feature.
I tried to use it like: login scenario needs username and password
- include-scenario: login
 properties:
   Username: Feature_user1
   Password: Feature_pswd1
- include-scenrio: feature1

for others in the similar style.
- include-scenario: login
  properties:
   Username: Feature_user2
   Password: Feature_pswd2
- include-scenario: feature2

It's not working. I am getting an error:  ERROR:  Config error: Wrong request
In https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/ it says about Scenario-Level properties.
I am accessing these properties like: ${${__P(Username)}} and ${${__P(Password)}}
Any pointers to solve this.

I don't think you can achieve this because:

When you use include-scenario blocks it results into a single Test Plan so you won't be able to use different properties for different child scenarios
Neither properties nor variables are propagated into "parent" scenario from child scenarios

I think you can rather use JSR223 Blocks for setting different credentials for different scenarios, something like:
execution:
- concurrency: 1
  iterations: 1
  scenario: combined-scenario

scenarios:
  feature1:
    requests:
    - url: https://blazedemo.com?username=${username}&password=${password}
      method: GET
      jsr223:
        - execute: before
          script-text: 'vars.put("username", "feature-1-username"); vars.put("password", "feature-1-password")'
  feature2:
    requests:
    - url: https://demoblaze.com?username=${username}&password=${password}
      method: GET
      jsr223:
        - execute: before
          script-text: 'vars.put("username", "feature-2-username"); vars.put("password", "feature-2-password")'
  combined-scenario:
    requests:
      - include-scenario: feature1
      - include-scenario: feature2

More information:

JMeter Properties and Variables
Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?


In my case, I have same request login which has to execute, but it should take different username/password.
Feature1 - Scenario-Login should use user1/pswd1 followed by other scenarios and Feature2 - Scenario-Login should use user2/pswd2 followed by other scenarios.
